# How to Speed up VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a VBA containing a lot of chunks similar to the following:

```
Range("D82").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("L" & i + 4).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

I am wondering whether this the fastest way to do such tasks. Is there a way to speed up by using different coding?

Comment: Avoid .Select   Copy an entire range in one go, rather than loop, if possible. Difficult to tell with just the code above what else. Switch off things like screenupdating. Can you show more of the code? Also, if the code works but needs speeding up consider posting to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)  site instead but be sure to read their help pages for posting.

Comment: See [Avoiding select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: @Qharr Why doesn't this work, please? `Range("L" & j, "Q" & j).Value = Range("Mean").Value / Range("Units").Value` The error is "Type Mismatch"

Comment: Strange, still not working. It seems that the problem is `/ Range("Units").Value`. This range is one cell containing the unit (eg, 1000, 1000000).

Comment: How have you declared j? And what is in Range("Units") ?

Comment: I did not declare j. It is a simple looping variable `For j = Range("Scen_Start").Value To Range("Scen_End").Value`. In Range("Units"), it is just a cell, a constant 1000 or 1000000.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167983/discussion-between-latexfan-and-qharr).